# Why does my sprite get stuck when touching the bottom world bounds?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Nice to meet you all. This is my first post on Stackoverflow, I'm a Math & CS student and new to **[JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)** and **[Phaser 3](https://phaser.io/phaser3)**. I'm really enjoying the language and framework, but I"m running into this problem with world bounds. I'm hoping someone can help me.

I'm working on a single screen plat-former and I'd like to use the 'bottom' world bound as the ground the player can walk on and then just put a static image with no physics behind it. I'm using 'Arcade' physics and gravity: Y: 1000. Whenever the sprite falls onto the bottom world bound, it won't move. I'm using this bit of code. Thank you!

```
create(){

this.physics.world.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 550);

this.player1 = this.physics.add.sprite(game.config.width * 1 / 4, 300, 'playerSprite');
this.player1.setScale(3, 3);
this.player1.setSize(18,25).setOffset(15,6);
this.player1.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
}
```

Comment: Can you also include the code you're using to move your sprite?

Comment: It's probably because the physics system you've using is applying friction. So if you were using impulse force or something similar to move your character, that force might be too weak to overcome the friction.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I do not believe it has to do with the friction because if I use physics on a platform sprite, the character can move freely.

Comment: I'm not sure how to add code to the comment without it looking like a disaster

Comment: You can edit your original post to include the additional code. You should be able to access formatting guides while you're editing the post to see how to avoid looking like a disaster.

Answer (score 0):

check your phaser config, set enableSleeping to false

```js
enableSleeping: false
```